# Do sink shut-off valves have to be centered under the sink, one on left and one on right?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I’m re-doing a small bathroom and because of size constraints need to route both shut-offs on the left side under sink one above the other. They will be hidden and accessible inside the vanity. Is there any reason not to do this? Thank you.

Comment: The valves don't care.  As long as they are easily accessible, they can be almost any where.  You will probably need longer supply hoses for one side.

Comment: Just don’t put them so far down or sideways that the faucet hoses won’t reach. (Though if you had to, you can extend those hoses.)

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: It depends how much OCD you have.

Comment: This is also a good time to replace your braided water supply hoses.

Comment: Consider what might get shoved into the undersink-space for storage too, whether it can bash into the shutoffs.  When mounted behind the waste there is some level of protection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They do not have to be centered. It looks nice and organized but not a requirement. You want to make sure they are close enough to the faucet so the braided hoses that most people use today will reach. Keep in mind that the valves might have to be replaced some day so don't make it too hard to access them. You also have to operate them so keep that in mind. When installing them, make sure you label the hot and cold so you don't mess up hooking them to the faucet.

Comment: Thank you. Good things to keep in mind. I appreciate it.

Comment: Use 1/4 turn ball valves.   They last longer than gate valves.

Comment: & With red and blue handles, no labels needed, even.